# Trusted web activity (TWA) in combination with native in app purchase

Tags: java, android, progressive-web-apps, twa

I'm using a TWA as almost my whole app. The only problem, I want to use the native
in app purchase system that google is offering.

Everywhere I look there is a sentence that you can use native stuff like push notifications, in app purchase etc.

What I want: A tabbed app (first tab is the pwa, second tab a native screen). But I can't find any information on this.

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Comment: Nope, I am experimenting with deep links. So that I can display a native view inside the app.

Comment: I suspect you're onto something. From what I can tell you can link to another activity and use that.